# Children's novel about girl whose guardian is her elder brother

Tags: identification-request

I've been trying to find the name and author of a "realistic fiction" children's novel (age 7-12-ish) written somewhere in the early 2000s (I read it in 2014) which takes place in a small English town.
The cover art resembles that of Jacqueline Wilson's books, though it isn't any of hers. It contains some pink and a picture of the main character (a young girl) in the centre. The title is associated with the girl's name, possibly containing *May* or *Mayflower*.

I remember a good amount of the plot:

Basically the main character's parents are dead. She lives with her adult brother and sister. One day she's travelling on a train with her brother, and the man sitting across from them has a red aeroplane-shaped birthday cake, for his son. She advises him to place the cake on top of his newspaper, to stop it sliding around as the train moves. Eventually he leaves, leaving his newspaper behind, in which the girl's brother sees an ad for gardener or caretaker of a private property. Presumably he applies for the job and gets it. When the girl and her brother travel to the place, they find that the owner of the house is the same man from the train.

The rest of the book, as far as I remember, revolves around the girl and the owner's son investigating the "mystery" of strange noises coming from I think the attic. They find out at the end that the noises were from the elderly housekeeper secretly watching television, as the house owner does not like computers/TV, and doesn't allow the children to use these. (The housekeeper assumes this rule applies to her as well.)

Comment: No need to apologise, long is good! The more details you include, the more likely that someone can find it :-)